# Add to cart not working in custom template magento2

Tags: product, addtocart, repository

I am getting add to cart url by product object like below.

Block file.

```
 use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;     
 use \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart as CartHelper;
 class CustomAdd extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
  { 
   protected $_productRepository; 
   protected $cartHelper;
   public function __construct(
      ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
      )
     {   
      $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
       $this->cartHelper = $cartHelper;
     }

   public function getAddToCartUrlForProduct($productSku)
   {
     $product = $this->_productRepository->get($productSku);
     return $this->cartHelper->getAddUrl($product);
   }
 }
```

Using like below in template

```
   <?php 
    $addtoCartUrl = $block->getAddToCartUrlForProduct(11101);
   ?>
  <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="checkout-sec">
            <a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></a>                
            <p><a href="<?php echo $addtoCartUrl; ?>" class="btn-addtocart">Add to Cart</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is not adding the product to cart. can anyone please suggest me . Where i am wrong here. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting correct add to cart url?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, yes i got like below, cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2VjMi0zNC0yNDQtNTctMjEwLmV1LXdlc3QtMS5jb21wdXRlLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vQXNobW9sZWFuL2NoZWNrb3V0L2NhcnQv/product/7967/in_cart/1/, but its not adding when i add it

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, tried but not worked for me

Comment: @SukumarGorai, 2.2.6 is my magento version, have u checked it?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, can you please update your answer with html also? Its not working for me with that code

Comment: @SukumarGorai, Are you using 2.2.6?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, can you help me on this issue please? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code instead of yours:

```
class CustomAdd extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
  protected $_productRepository; 
  protected $_listProduct;
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProduct
  )
  {   
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_listProduct = $listProduct;
  }

  public function getAddToCartUrlForProduct($id)
  {
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    return $this->_listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
  }
}
```

Run di:compile and other required commands and test.

Comment: tried your solution, its not worked for me, replaced _listBlock to _listProduct, still not worked

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: no error, page will refresh once add to cart is clicked, but product not added to cart

Comment: Can you try it in private browser?

Comment: yes tried in private window also, same issue

Comment: What is the magento version you are using? Also check it in default magento2 installation.

Comment: my magento version is 2.2.6

Comment: Its working correctly in my instance.

Comment: Can you please share your html code also?